# Прочитать PDF с сайта

Tags: java, android, pdf

В процессе создания приложения понадобилось чтение `.pdf` с сайта.  Каким образом можно вычленить текст файла?

При помощи [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) я могу спарсить страницу со ссылками, а [iText](https://itextpdf.com/en) позволит мне прочитать pdf, но что поможет "открыть" pdf, не скачивая его на устройство?

Comment: Это в принципе невозможно, скачать придётся.

Answer (score 1):

Если перевести на русский язык, вы хотите получить возможность парсинга PDF файла в потоке, то есть последовательно, а не всего файла в целом.

К сожалению, в большинстве случаем это невозможно. Первая версия стандарта [ISO-32000-1](https://www.iso.org/standard/51502.html), описывающего PDF формат вообще говорится:

> Conforming readers should read a PDF file from its end.

Ну то есть читать надо с конца...

Во второй версии немного по другому, но не менее безрадостно:

> With the exception of linearized PDF files, all PDF files should be read using the trailer and cross-reference table as described in the following subclauses. Reading a non-linearized file in a serial manner is not reliable because of the way objects are to be processed after an incremental update. (See 6.3.2, "Conformance of PDF processors".)

В общем в итоге, вам по любому придется сначала прочитать/скачать весь PDF файл и только потом провести его разбор/парсинг.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишите клиентское приложение - то никак нельзя прочесть файл не скачав его.

Однако вы можете воспользоваться онлайн-сервисами которые скачают его за вас и выдадут вам представление в виде plaintext из которого вы сможете вычленить нужные вам слова. Со стороны клиента вы вообще с pdf не будете работать в этом случае.

В конце концов вы можете такой сервис сами написать и использовать его в клиентском приложении.